# How many binary sequences of length 7 have at least two 1's?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many binary sequences of length 7 have at least two 1's? Can someone please explain the procedure in detail please. I tried solving it using the "count what you do not want" procedure, but I got nowhere. Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you get if you count those that have exactly zero or exactly one 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of $7$-digit sequences is $2^7=128$

The number of $7$-digit sequences with $0$ occurrences of "one" is $\binom70=1$

The number of $7$-digit sequences with $1$ occurrence  of "one" is $\binom71=7$

The number of $7$-digit sequences with $2$ or more occurrences of "one" is $128-(1+7)=120$

Comment: @MathLover95: You're welcome :)